# Sending Push Notification Slows the UI in Xamarin Forms using One Signal

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I have implemented push notifications in my Xamarin Forms App but I am facing an issue which is in regards to unresponsiveness of the UI when the Push Notification is executed as it is not Asynchronous. Hence, could you please help me improve this code so the UI doesn't freeze when sending each push.

The following is the code:

```
     private void Sendbtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Some code for the message.

         if (userOffline)
              SendPushNotification(pushMessage);

    }


            private void SendPushNotification(Messages pushMessage)
           {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications") as HttpWebRequest;

        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        string appId = "{app ID}";
        var header_Name = new { en = userName };
        var subheader_Name = new { en = title };
        var contentsMessage = new { en = pushMessage.message };
        string[] deviceID = Devices;

        var obj = new
        {
            app_id = appId,
            headings = header_Name,
            subtitle = subheader_Name,
            contents = contentsMessage,
            include_player_ids = deviceID
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        string responseContent = null;
        
        try
        {
            using (var writer = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

Comment: WebRequest support async operations - have you tried them?

Comment: Thanks @Jason. I implemented the async operations of the WebRequest and it has solved my issue. Thanks buddy.